# Unity iOS build failure: duplicate symbol for speech recognition in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I'm trying to build my Unity app on Xcode; it includes a plugin bought on the Asset Store (Mobile Speech Recognizer), which adds a framework to my project at build time (Speech.framework) and it's .a file as well (KKSpeechRecognizer.a). Well, when I build in Xcode, I get this error:

> duplicate symbol '_StringFromKKSpeechRecognitionAuthorizationStatus'
>   in:
>       /Users/user/Desktop/something/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/KKSpeechRecognizer.a(KKSpeechRecognizer.o)
>       /Users/user/Desktop/something/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/KKSpeechRecognizer.a(UnitySpeechRecognizerDelegate.o)
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

I'm trying to open/modify that file (KKSpeechRecognizer.a), but I can't find a way to get to it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been addressed in the support forum: http://www.kokosoft.pl/forums/topic/unity-ios-build-failure-duplicate-symbol-for-speech-recognition-in-xcode/

You need to replace Assets/Plugins/iOS/KKSpeechRecognizer.a with the version posted there.